# Subscribe to Multiple Topics and Callback Function

Tags: ros, callback, function, multiple, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to write a node in python which subscribes to multiple topics using only one callback function. What's the correct way to do this? For instance, I want to compare the values published on two different topics (`cmd_vel` and `base_velocity`) in a callback function. I'm assuming these two topics are being published continuously, so I think I want a callback when both topics are updated

```
def callback(data):
    if cmdVel == baseVelocity:
        # Do Step 1
    else:
        # Do Step 2
    
def listener():
    
    rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel', Twist, callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('base_velocity', Twist, callback)
           
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    rospy.init_node('robot_controller', anonymous=True)
    listener()
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196065/subscribe-to-multiple-topics-and-callback-function/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: The original question asked, in short "Can I subscribe and pass the same callback to multiple subscribers". I assumed you wanted to process different messages with different types in the same way, using the same callback.

The original answer was:

> That looks like it should work, bug beware
> that your callback will be called with
> different messages with different
> types, so you'll have to check the
> message type and do something
> different for each type.
>
> Alternately, you could define a
> different callback for each topic,
> have each callback parse the message
> into a common format, and then pass
> that to a common method which
> implements the actual program logic.

EDIT:

I'm no longer sure what you're expecting ROS to do for you.

- Do you want a callback whenever you get either message?
- Do you want a callback only when both topics are updated?
- Are you just trying to avoid keeping a copy of each most recent message?

EDIT:

You can use [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) to subscribe to multiple topics and get a callback when all topics have new messages. Unless your publishers are explicitly publishing messages with identical timestamps, you'll probably want to use the [ApproximateTimeSynchronizer](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-27**:
Thanks. Is it possible to have a callback function with multiple arguments"

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-27**:
and whether this [message filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) is related to my question?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-27**:
See the rospy [Subscriber API](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-27**:
What do you want to do with multiple callback arguments? You may want to expand your question with more details about your use case.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-27**:
Updated my question. Thanks

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-27**:
I'm assuming these two topics are being published continuously, so I think I want a callback when both topics are updated